# how add some check for a dynamic select list

Tags: javascript, html

I have a Visa validity date column from a select type element, and I've made all of my lists inside the JavaScript and want to check if something was chosen, but I need the list to load when the page loads.
I made the trigger event onload but that provide a problem because if the event is onload it's going to check the function only on load and not after that, and if I make the empty options into HTML and leave the JavaScript on load it doesn't even show me the month/year options.
If I make change the trigger to onclick it make it buggy, and what I mean in that is that I have to click one time on the list and it shows me one option, then I have to leave the list and then click again.
Can someone give me an idea on how to do that, and whether I can make event into a function? If yes, how?

JS code:

```
function cardDateValidity() {
    var month = "<option value=''>Month</option>";
    var monthOption = document.getElementById("cardmonth");
    var yearOption = document.getElementById("cardyear");
    var year = "<option value=''>Year</option>";

    for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
        month += "<option value=" + i + ">" + i + "</option>";
        monthOption.innerHTML = month;
    }

    for (var i = 1991; i <= 2100; i++) {
        year += "<option value=" + i + ">" + i + "</option>";
        yearOption.innerHTML = year;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<body onload="cardDateValidity()">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p class="RegTextLine">validity card date</p>
            <select id="cardmonth"/>
            <select id="cardyear"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you man for correcting me. (no sarcasm)

Comment: Do you just want to make sure something has been selected?

Comment: yes, you completly right

Answer (score 0):

You can call a function with `onchange` event. Then you can handle the change event in any way you want. here is the working code: [link](http://jsbin.com/mitufikedu/1/edit?html,js,output)